# How to remove the gaps on my toolbar without changing the layout of my listview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am creating a toolbar. I have everything in place, but I am unable to get rid of the gaps that occur on both sides as well as the top. It seems to be mimicking the gaps of listview,which is underneath it. I know that I can delete the padding attributes in the relative layout.  The problem is that when I do that, the listview's layout (which is at the bottom of the toolbar) changes along with it and I want it to be the way it is.  Does anybody have suggestions on how to get rid of those unwanted gaps while keeping the layout of the rest of my activity?

[image: Here are some pictures of my toolbar and listview]

[image]

Here is my xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.jesse.myapp.FavoriteActivity">


    <include
        layout="@layout/favoritebar"
        android:id="@+id/fb"/>     

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/languageselector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkboxtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="NO FAVORITES AVAILABLE"
        android:textColor="#525252"
        android:textSize="19.0sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checklist"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/arrow2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text=""/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the xml file for the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme= "@style/Toolbarstyle">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat your question

Comment: It wasn't a repetition of my question

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @Fgf567 share your code for **`favoritebar`** layout

Comment: Lolz, it was a different question.  Do you think that I should keep the original post, which has answers that don't have anything to do with the question?

Comment: It is a different question because I am asking how to remove the gaps without changing the rest of the layout, not simply remove the gaps.

Comment: That’s why I asked a different question- because I did not mention it in my other question So I asked a new Question.  The answers did not reflect what I really wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you want the relative layout content as it is:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include
    layout="@layout/favoritebar"
    android:id="@+id/fb"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.jesse.myapp.FavoriteActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/languageselector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkboxtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="NO FAVORITES AVAILABLE"
        android:textColor="#525252"
        android:textSize="19.0sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checklist"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/arrow2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text=""/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```